# Late Model 2011 Macbook Pro with SSD appears to be off somehow

Tags: mac, ssd, macbook-pro

Ok, I just got a SSD for my Macbook Pro Late-2011. The specs from what I read are that the laptop is capable of 6gbps, so I got myself a OZC Agility 240gb 6gbps SSD. Decided to join the club and speed test it with Blackmagic Disk Speed Test.. and the results are equivilent to that of a 3gbps setup. So.. I am wondering overall is there a configuration setting somewhere I can tweak?

The original HD was a 500gb HDD the spinning kind. So I'm figuring maybe thats why there may be a setting somewhere hidden I dunno about that I can tweak, just wanna see if anyone else knows if this is the case.

***edit***
should also mention did a fresh factory install, nothing carried over from original hd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look in system profiler (apple menu / about this mac - i believe in lion its called a system report) you'll be able to see the negotiated speed of the link for your hard disk.

if it says 3GBs negotiated speed (and i bet it does), thats your answer.

heres what happened:

you replaced your old drive (which was 3GBs) and installed a 6GBs drive -- OSX isnt smart enough to actually re-negotiate the link, so it's still passing data at the lower speed.

if you do an SMC reset on your mac (google it, its been a while since i owned a macbook) your system will renegotiate the link, and get full sata3 6GBs speeds.

same thing happened to me on my early 2011 13" macbook pro.

hope that helps!