# MacBook Pro Late 2011 is working very very slow although the configuration is not that old

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

[image: Hardware Test Results]

[image: MacBook Hardware Profile]

I received as a gift from a friend a late 2011 MacBook Pro he was using until not so long ago for video editing and worked fine for a long period of time.

But now, for some reason it is moving very slow although the configuration of the MacBook is not that old.

I mean, there is a 500GB SSD Drive and the rest of the configuration you can see in the Hardware Profile in image above.

With freshely installed Mac OS that I updated to the Yosemite Version up to now.

Websites like YouTube don't work at all, only if the tab is not active I can mannage to listen to a song for example.

I ran an Apple Hardware Test. There is an image above with the result.

What can I do to make it work to its normal performance?

I usually use a Lenovo Laptop with Windows on it. Not that familiar with Mac's and Mac OS;

Answer (score 0):

I tried a SMC Reset and it seems it works much better now.

Found some info in this questions answers: [Late Model 2011 Macbook Pro with SSD appears to be off somehow](https://superuser.com/questions/433184/late-model-2011-macbook-pro-with-ssd-appears-to-be-off-somehow)

I used the information in this article: https://www.avast.com/c-reset-mac-pram-smc

LATER UPDATE 1:
It seems that the SMC Reset Works, but only for about an hour. After that it slowly begins to run slowly again. If I repeat and do the SMC Reset again it works for another hour then back in the slums.

Another image attached from the "Intel Power Gadget" App. This is immediately after the SMC Reset, Will try to run it again when it gets slowly again.
[image: This is immediately after the SMC Reset, Will try to run it again when it gets slowly again.]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Following the other discussion, could you check at which frequency the CPU is now operating? You need to install the "Intel Power Gadget" utility for that...

Comment: @PierU , check the screenshot. This is imediately after the SMC Reset. I will try to add another one after the laptop starts moving slowly again.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple Diagnostic is returning an error about the battery. (Unsurprising on an 11-year-old laptop.)

If the battery cannot deliver sufficient power to the laptop (or if it is absent), the CPU will be [severely throttled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380493/cpu-throttling-on-macbook-with-bad-battery-and-catalina). The mains power supply is there to charge the battery, not to power the laptop.

You can buy replacement batteries, though bear in mind they are all 'generic' products, as Apple don't sell their own parts for these; so the quality is a gamble.

Also, make sure that the SSD is not full: keep at least 50Gb of free space. Newer OSes rely on using more RAM -- if it isn't maxed out at 16Gb, see if you can get some old compatible memory sticks.

Comment: Most laptops can operate normally even with a dead battery. Assuming of course the AC adapter is a genuine one, or has the required power output in case of a third-party one.

Comment: @PierU No, Apple laptops will throttle the CPU if the battery cannot supply power. That's why I mentioned it!

Comment: The point is "severely" throttled. I can get the fact that for instance the turbo modes are disabled to avoid power peaks , but an under-clock to 1.2GHz like in your link looks more like a security mode, which is not justified by what the adapter can provide. Besides, many people use old MacBooks with dead batteries, only an AC power, without complaining... And as a matter of fact, the poster apparently got satisfactory performances after a SMC reset: would be interesting if he could check the frequency now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a saga troubleshooting this MacBook Pro.

The battery was recently replaced because the old one was bloated. I'm gonna look down this path also. Will come back if something new pops up.

Comment: @FlaviusFrantz You can check the battery health with the "Coconut Battery" utility.